# How To force firefox to store FLV files in %TEMP%\acro_rd_dir instead of Firefox cache?

Tags: firefox, flash, browser-cache

I am using [VideoCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html) to save videos that I have already watched, *VideoCacheView* saves FLV files from the folder `%TEMP%\acro_rd_dir` but sometimes, the embedded flash player does not save FLV files in `%TEMP%\acro_rd_dir`, but it stores them in the cache of firefox as split files (`C:\Documents and Settings\nvarm\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\d74svniy.default\Cache`), so the *VideoCacheView*  can not save them.

I am wondering why sometimes it stores same video in `acro_rd_dir` and other times stores it in Firefox cache as split files.

my Question :

How To force firefox to store FLV files in `%TEMP%\acro_rd_dir` instead of Firefox cache?

Comment: I doubt you can force Firefox to do anything, because this is most likely the Flash plugin's doing.